# Сокращение «г.р.»

Tags: сокращение

Нужен ли пробел? Г.р. или г. р.?

Answer (score 2):

Все подобные сокращения есть слова́ с отсечёнными частями. Между словами мы ведь ставим пробелы. Значит, между "г. р." и в подобных случаях также следует ставить пробелы.

Подробнее [здесь](https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html). Конкретно "г. р." в списке РАН отсутствует, но имеется масса аналогичных случаев.

Answer (score 1):

Запись с пробелом

Словарь сокращений: https://www.sokr.ru/

Запись № 9078
Добавлена 11.10.2002
г. р.
год рождения

https://www.sokr.ru/card/9078s343162cc/